# Как скрыть линию под прозрачным блоком?

Tags: html, css

Нужно скрыть линию в полукруге, но не заливая его белым цветом. Как это сделать?
Пытался добавлять линии через before и after абсолютно по 50% ширины, но это на адаптивно, на разных разрешениях линия разной длины получалась.

```css
.complex {
  padding: 100px 0;
}
.line-box {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3962b5;
  position: relative;
}
.ico-complex-box {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.ico-complex-box:before {
  content: "";
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #3962b5;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(auto, auto, 65px, 65px);
}
.ico-complex-box:after {
  content: "";
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #3962b5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  clip: rect(auto, 65px, 65px, auto);
}
```

```html
<section class="complex">
  <div class="top-line-box">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="ico-complex-box">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.complex {
  padding: 100px 0;
}
.line-box {
  position: relative;
}

.line-box:before,
.line-box:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: calc(50% - 65px);
  background: #3962b5;
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.line-box:after {
  right: 0;
}

.ico-complex-box {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.ico-complex-box:before {
  content: "";
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #3962b5;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(auto, auto, 65px, 65px);
}

.ico-complex-box:after {
  content: "";
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #3962b5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  clip: rect(auto, 65px, 65px, auto);
}
```

```html
<section class="complex">
  <div class="top-line-box">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="ico-complex-box">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно.